# Manually delete resolvers from a project on AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm currently using Amazon's dashboard to create my schema and attach a resolver. When I do a pull request on my command line to sync my changes to my front end client, I pull all the resolvers that were ever created (even the ones where I deleted the associated type in the schema). Is there a way to manually remove resolvers from my AppSync backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS CLI and call the delete resolver with the following parameters.

```
  delete-resolver
     --api-id <value>
     --type-name <value>
     --field-name <value>
```

I am on the AWS AppSync team and I will bring this issue up with the team.

Comment: Update after 4 years: This still cannot be achieved via AWS console, so this workaround is the only option